# Old Passport with US Visa FNU

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, passport-renewals

I have valid US B1/B2 Visa on an expired Indian passport. My passport has my surname as blank and hence I was issued a US Visa with given name as FNU and Surname *"My First Name"* . I need to apply for new passport and I am planning to get my given name and the surname correct in the new passport.

My questions are:

1. Will I have problems travelling to US if my new passport says my given name as *"my first name"* and surname as *"My last name"* but my valid visa on old passport says given name as FNU and Surname as *"my first name"*
2. Or should I again apply for my new passport with just my first name and keeping my surname as blank, which I am not in favor of.

Comment: Hi, so were you able to travel without having to apply for a new visa?

Answer (score 6):

You new passport should have your complete, legal name as verified by some other document (such as your birth certificate or national card).

As far as your valid US visa is concerned, the State department [says the following](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html):

> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court
>   ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you
>   have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply
>   for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from
>   the United States.

In your case, you should submit your old passport and visa, new passport and a letter explaining the name change to the US Embassy. They will most likely issue you a visa on your new passport, invalidating the old visa.

Comment: "Having a travel document no surname can cause problems later" -- no, it's actually quite common in some countries, including India.  The problem here is the difference between the name in the visa and the passport, not the lack of surname.