# Should I apply for a new passport because of FNU in US Visa at this moment?

Tags: usa, passports, f1-visas

I have read this post: [Old Passport with US Visa FNU](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/77340/old-passport-with-us-visa-fnu) and I understood what the US travel website recommends. But I want to know the answer in the context of my current situation in the travelling steps listed below:

As per my knowledge, the following are the steps to travel the to US as a student:

1. Recieve an I-20 from a university
2. Get an F1 Visa from a US Embassy/Consultate.

> **I am here right now**

3. Board on a flight the to US
4. Get the I-94 at the Port of Entry
5. Get Social Security Number, Drivers license etc.

##### Table 1:

My passport has the following mistake:

| Surname | Given Name |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN APPLESEED |  |

##### Table 2:

Whereas my real name should look like this:

| Surname | Given Name |
| --- | --- |
| APPLESEED | JOHN |

I learned about the name error in step 2 above, during my biometrics just before my Visa Interview. It was too late for me to get a new passport with the correct details, so I had to proceed with step 2 with my erroneous passport.

##### Table 3:

Hence, my US visa stamp has been issued with:

| Surname | Given Name |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN APPLESEED | FNU |

Now, I have less than 4 weeks of time before I reach step 3. My question is should I even bother getting my passport updated with the correct details as mentioned in Table 2.

If I get a new passport with the name details corrected as per Table 2 and don't get my visa stamp updated, will I face any issues while entering the US or with government authorities such as DMV or while getting an SSN?

At this moment I cannot get my Visa stamp updated since there are no appointment slots available at the nearest US embassy.

Comment: What country are you from? In some countries like Malaysia, even for people who have names which can actually be separated in given name/surname, passports only carry a single "name", with everything in the the surname and no given name, so you just can't get it "corrected" because it is considered correct.

Comment: @jcaron my passport is Indian.

Comment: @Dipunj were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @nomadinthedark I didn't change my passport and so far I haven't faced any issues. Most immigration authorities in US seem to understand this issue now.

Comment: @Dipunj Did you face any issues in step 4 or 5? Is it better to get a new passport with name split instead of having FNU?

Comment: @AbhijayKumar No issues in step 4, I got an SSN too without the FNU in it – no problems so far. Haven't yet applied for a driving license. If you already have the visa stamp, I would advise not to get it split. However, if you haven't even started the visa process (DS-160), then I would suggest to go ahead and get it split.